# IDA Pro patching issue

Tags: reverse-engineering

I have built a open source program by me and I was using it to practice on Disassembly techniques But I am very use to ollydbg program but In there when you find the address in ollydbg you can put nop's which is no operations and you can then copy to executable you are patching and save it then you got a fix but In in IDA Pro disassembler program how do you do the nop's like ollydbg Or IS it a different kind of setting that I need to choose that's my question.... Thanks for the help....

I have tried other things but only in ollydbg instead of ida pro

Answer (score 0):

There is no special command for that. But IDA has very powerful script languages engine. You can write simple script in IDC or python, like this:

IDC:

```
// NOP from 0x401357 to 0x401380
auto ea = 0x401357;
auto end_ea = 0x401380;
while (ea < end_ea) {
    patch_byte(ea, 0x90);
    ea = ea + 1;
}
```

python:

```
# NOP from 0x401357 to 0x401380
ea = 0x401357
end_ea = 0x401380
while ea < end_ea:
    patch_byte(ea, 0x90)
    ea = ea + 1
```

Another option is to use plug-ins. Community created many useful plug-ins. One of them is ida-patcher. I never used it, but look at the PR #1 on github. It adds ability to NOP region of memory, like same feature in the OllyDbg.